# Verilog Synchronous 4 bit Counter stay on max value until given signal

Tags: verilog, counter, synchronous, test-bench

So I have my counter in verilog which is 4 bits and I want it to stay on max value, 1111, until I give it a signal to start counting from 0000 again.

Here's what I've been able to come up with so far:

```
module contadorAscMax
(
    input iClk,
    input iRst,
    output oQ,
    input iCE,
    input iSignal,
    output [3:0] orCnt
);

reg[3:0] rvCnt_d;
reg[3:0] rvCnt_q;

assign orCnt = rvCnt_q;

always @(posedge iClk or posedge iRst)
begin
    if(iRst)
    begin
        rvCnt_q<=4'b0;
    end
    else
    begin
        if(iCE)
        begin
            rvCnt_q<=rvCnt_d;
        end
        else
        begin
            rvCnt_q<=rvCnt_q;
        end
    end
end
always @*
begin
    rvCnt_d=rvCnt_q+4'b1;
    if(rvCnt_d == 4'b1111)
    begin
        rvCnt_d = rvCnt_d;
    end
    else if(rvCnt_d == 4'b1111 & iSignal)
    begin
        rvCnt_d = 4'b0;
    end
end


endmodule
```

But it just won't wait for the signal. I am very new to verilog so my code probable doesn't make much sense to a hardware guy, since I am a software engineer so sorry if there are some rookie mistakes here.

As for the testbench, here is what I have:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module vtfContMax;

    // Inputs
    reg iClk;
    reg iRst;
    reg iCE;
    reg iSignal;

    // Outputs
    wire oQ;
    wire [3:0] orCnt;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    contadorAscMax uut (
        .iClk(iClk), 
        .iRst(iRst), 
        .oQ(oQ), 
        .iCE(iCE), 
        .iSignal(iSignal), 
        .orCnt(orCnt)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        iClk = 1;
        iRst = 1;
        iCE = 1;
        iSignal = 0;

        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
        #10;
        iRst = 0;


        repeat(10)
        begin
            repeat(10)
            begin
                wait(iClk);
                wait(!iClk);
            end
        end
        $stop();

        // Add stimulus here

    end

    always
    begin
        #5;
        iClk = ~iClk;
        #10
        iSignal = ~iSignal;
    end

endmodule
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have split the code in a register and combinatorial section. Although that is a good idea for complex logic, for a simple 4 bit counter it is a bit over the top.

For solving your problem you are close. The trick with code like this, is to make the definition using 'programming' language. Then the code flows from that.
*I want to have a counter which goes from 1111 to 0000 when a signal is present, **else** I want it to count up.*
This then leads to:

```
always @(clk or posedge reset)
begin
   if (reset)
      count <= 4'b1111;
   else
   begin
       if (count==4'b1111 && start_signal)
          count <= 4'b0000;
       else
          count <= count + 4'b0001
   end
end
```

What you don't mention, but what I see from your code you also have an enable (iCE) and an unused output oQ. The total then becomes:

```
module contadorAscMax
(
    input iClk,
    input iRst,
//    output oQ,
    input iCE,
    input iSignal,
   output reg [3:0] orCnt
);
always @(iClk or posedge iRst)
begin
   if (iRst)
      orCnt <= 4'b0000; // or should that be 4'b1111
      // Is this really what you want? 
      // It will start counting after a reset!
   else
   begin
       if (iCE)
       begin
          if (orCnt==4'b1111 && iSignal)
             orCnt <= 4'b0000;
          else
             orCnt <= orCnt+ 4'b0001;
       end
   end
end
endmodule
```

Some more remarks:
Your reset condition looks flawed to me but you have to solve that.
Give the counter enable signal a decent name: 'count_enable' not 'signal'.

Last: I would not use all the 'i's and 'o's. The 'o' signals from one module will be the 'i' of another. Thus you have to change the signal names somewhere. It is better to have a defined signal in your system. If only so you can find in the timing report or gates after synthesis.